# Web Filter Alternative to OpenDNS

Tags: dns, web-filtering, content-filtering

The company I work for currently uses OpenDNS to block undesirable websites (adult content, racist/tasteless content, social media, games, etc.). They're honestly pretty relaxed in doing this, but I've encountered a few issues that annoy me.

The biggest issue with OpenDNS is that it doesn't support wildcard filtering. As an example, my company blocks facebook.com (for obvious reasons). This is fine by me, but, in doing so, it also blocks Facebook's React API. As a result, I'm unable to access [hemmingwayapp.com](http://www.hemingwayapp.com/).

OpenDNS **does** support implied wildcards (blocking facebook.com will also block connect.facebook.com) but not explicit wildcards. What I'd like to be able to do is something similar to the following:

#### Always Block:

- `*facebook.com*`

#### Never Block

- `*facebook.com/react*`

### Criteria Alternative MUST Meet:

- Supports wildcards (`*facebook.com/react*`)
- Up-to-date, comprehensive, categorical filtering (blanket block content such as adult content and social media)
- Customizable blacklist and whitelist
- Network-wide blocking (we're not going to push an app to all PCs on the network just to replace OpenDNS)

### Bonus Criteria:

- Regex support
- Free or one-time purchase strongly preferred
- Open Source
- Content-aware analysis and filtering?

Comment: Any update? This is an interesting question, I'm curious to know if you found a good answer to it.